# Blazor Server App with Microsoft Identity Authenticaion (Azure AD) gets stuck in authentication loop after publishing to local IIS 10 (Server 2019)

Tags: iis, blazor, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

I have been testing a Blazor Server app (ASP.NET Core 6.0) locally for a while with no issues. It authenticates against Azure AD, and everything works fine.

I deployed it to an IIS 10 server on Windows Server 2019 (after installing Websockets, ASP.NET hosting runtime, etc.) and now I can't get past authentication, either locally on the server or remotely.

When I hit the URL, it immediately redirects to the Microsoft Login page, where I enter my username (email), then password, then 2FA challenge, then the yes/no stay logged in page, and then it appears to hang for a short while (although in the tab it is constantly switching between "Working" and "https://login.microsoft.com...") and then it either comes up with Bad Request - Request Too Long, or just "We can't sign you in".

If it's the Bad Request error, then the cookie store will be full of .AspNetCore.Correlation.xxx and .AspNetCore.OpenIdConnectNonce.xxx cookies, which is what makes the headers too long, and creates the bad request. If it's the "we can't sign you in" error, then clicking the three dots, and saying sign out and forget, resets things which will next time result in the Bad Request error.

[image: Screenshot of network calls]

Just to check that I hadn't done anything stupid, I created a new blank app, using the Blazor Server template, and deployed that in place of my app. Exactly the same thing happened. I could run it locally in VS, but after publishing to IIS, exactly the same Authentication errors.

Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, for anyone who finds this in the future... it was a simple fix - but there are no error messages which point to it until you look very deeply.

When I set up both my app, and the Blazor template app, I let the scaffolder set them up, and get a secret from the Azure API, which it placed into my local secret store.

When I published the app to IIS, the ClientSecret was not copied.

The quick fix was to simply put the client secret into the appsettings.json file at which point everything came good immediately. The longer fix is to use the server-based secret store.

Apparently the looping was caused by the client secret not being present. :(

Comment: You can definitely mark as an answer. as indicated in the Microsoft tutorial [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-blazor-server)  the client secret must be rewritten in appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes to this question with a similar problem for a deployed Azure App Service that similarly gets stuck in a loop of authenticating the user then the answer is SIMILAR but not the same.

You may have a valid Client Secret in your appsettings.json file, and all seems to work perfectly locally.  When deployed the reality is this value may be being ignored in favour of one being stored in the app deployment slot.

To check this, use Kudu to check the deployed settings modify the URL to your deployed server, appending a .scm. between the host name and domain.

e.g. instead of

https://myapp.azurewebsites.net

use

https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net

Under the section 'REST API' click on the 'App Settings' link, and search for the Client Secret (for example 'AzureAD__ClientSecret')

If it doesn't match the one in your appsettings.json, then you need to modify the 'Configuration' under the relevant App Service within Azure.